# Error: > transaction invalidated with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE)

Tags: hyperledger

I have HLF 2.0 and am changing fabcar. I find the default runs but when I change fabcar I get this endless endorsement policy failure. I know the theory which is the peers have not endorsed the package but I cannot find out where is the error and how to corrects.

I seem to have a wrong package on one peer, I tried correcting to v3 on the chaincode but the orderer then states I cannot go from 1 to 3 on the commit.

Any ideas are welcome.

Failing command -

> peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o localhost:7050
> --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
> --name fabcar $PEER_CONN_PARMS --version ${VERSION} --sequence ${VERSION} --init-required 2020-08-01 07:38:23.823 UTC [chaincodeCmd]
> ClientWait -> INFO 001 txid
> [0ac232af717e2a48cf1e4fbb97c7bab38d568c275563245e37ee7ce836afb20c]
> committed with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE) at  Error:
> transaction invalidated with status (ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE)

query installed -

> peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalledInstalled chaincodes on peer:
> Package ID:
> fabcar_1:2939b5f219f516bc94df2253438bad440d6a91432f6b5bbd17ef05d2228766e8,
> Label: fabcar_1 Package ID:
> fabcar_3:ab8fb1f4b201d2b1af09d235308078534edfd1276da04a95a152a3f8d5db2893,
> Label: fabcar_3 Package ID:
> fabcar_2:ceda76aadba6c6cd34473fe7f21126dcc8100ac82b6e3cfe3c13e6c358f81291,
> Label: fabcar_2

Other peer -

> peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalledInstalled chaincodes on peer:
> Package ID:
> fabcar_1:2939b5f219f516bc94df2253438bad440d6a91432f6b5bbd17ef05d2228766e8,
> Label: fabcar_1 Package ID:
> fabcar_2:9aecae725e359eb8d2d56c5071eb2b5a52f0776f163a14de3dc6083320ef5d2c,
> Label: fabcar_2 Package ID:
> fabcar_3:ab8fb1f4b201d2b1af09d235308078534edfd1276da04a95a152a3f8d5db2893,
> Label: fabcar_3 Package ID:
> fabcar_2:ceda76aadba6c6cd34473fe7f21126dcc8100ac82b6e3cfe3c13e6c358f81291,
> Label: fabcar_2

Orderer -

> peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted -C mychannel Committed
> chaincode definitions on channel 'mychannel': Name: fabcar, Version:
> 1, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc
> ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-209:~/fabric-samples$

Comment: Can we have more log from all thd pods (orderer and peers) ?

Comment: This was solved now. The problem was related to the approve being done for one org1 only. I reran everything using the deployCC scripts and that worked.